# Opposite of Coupon Collector / Birthday Problems?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

There are $n$ combinatorial lists of a certain form.  I don't know what $n$ is.

I can randomly generate lists of that form.  Let's say that after a million such trials I've gotten 960000 distinct lists. Let's also assume my random method has an equal likelihood of picking any of the $n$ items from the complete list.

Based on that, is there a good guess for $n$?

The [coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) and [german tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) are related.

Is there a name for the problem?

Here's another version:  I randomly sample 1000 integers from 1 to $n$ and get 800 distinct values. What is a good guess for $n$?

Comment: I don't understand - what are combinatorial lists? Also what is the 'complete list'? Also what is the difference between items and lists? Could you please describe the sample space more precisely?

Comment: The items themselves are irrelevant, but there is a finite number of them.  For example, it could be possible birthdays.  After questioning 1000 people, you have gotten 334 distinct birthdays.  With that, can you estimate the number of days in a year?

Comment: This is generally just called support size estimation. It happens to be (as you would expect) closely related to entropy estimation, and tends to be studied in the same papers. 
Is the only information you have the number of distinct values? Do you have the list of all the samples you got? The sufficient statistic for this is the profile (or fingerprint, or histogram of histogram). That said you explicitly know the distribution to be uniform, so maybe that's enough, I don't know.

Comment: Check out, e.g., Valiant and Valiant's paper 'estimating the unseen' (and some of the papers citing it, maybe Jiao et al, Wu and Yang, etc - the talks in the distribution properties session here - https://simons.berkeley.edu/workshops/schedule/857 - may be of interest). For different approaches, check out Orlitsky's work on 'profile max likelihood'.

Comment: That said, for explicitly uniform distributions, you can build the max-likelihood for $n$ given the number of distinct samples easily, and that should do well if you have enough samples...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have $n$ items, and you randomly sample them $k$ times. You wind up with $D$ distinct items. If your random sampling produced the mean number of distinct items, you would expect that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{D-1} \dfrac{n}{n-i} = k$$

To simplify,

$$k = n(H_n-H_{n-D}) \approx n\log \dfrac{n}{n-D} \Longrightarrow n \approx \dfrac{kD}{D\cdot W\left( -\dfrac{ke^{-k/D}}{D} \right)+k}$$

where $W$ is the Lambert-W function.

So, for your examples:

$$k=10^6, D=9.6\times 10^5, n\approx 12,164,395$$

$$k=1000,D=334, n \approx 355.29$$

Comment: Is W the Lambert W function?

Comment: Good point, I should have specified. Yes, it is.

Comment: What a fantastically useful formula.  It's called the support size estimate?

Comment: Lol, I have no idea. I just took the formula from the Coupon-collector problem and told WolframAlpha to solve for $n$.

Answer (score 4):

The following develops an (approximate) MLE for $n$. I suppose that you take $s$ samples and see $d$ distinct elements. Note that

$$P( d \textrm{ distinct values in } s \textrm{ samples}; n) = \binom{n}{d}  \frac{1}{n^s} \times\sum_{\substack{s_1, \dots s_d \ge 1\\ \sum s_i = s}} \frac{s!}{\prod s_i!} $$

Now note that the term after $\times$ depends only on $s,d$ so it the same for each value of $n$. Thus, the MLE of $n$ is $$ \arg\max_{ n \ge d} \log \binom{n}{d} -s \log n$$

Using Stirling's approximation, one can show that $$ \log \binom{n}{d} = nh(d/n) + \frac{1}{2}\log \frac{n}{d(n-d)} + O(1),$$ where $h$ is the binary entropy.

So the MLE is roughly the maximiser of $f(n) := nh(d/n) + \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{n}{n-d} - s\log n $ (assuming $n \gg 1$).

Now, $$ \partial_n f =  \log \frac{n}{n-d} - \frac{s}{n} - \frac{d}{2n(n-d)}.$$ Setting this to $0$ gives $$ \hat{n}\left(\log \frac{\hat{n}}{\hat{n} - d} - \frac{d}{2(\hat{n}-d)}\right) = s,$$

which is very similar to the estimate presented by Interstellar probe. In particular, for $s = 1000, d = 344,$ it gives the solution $\hat{n} = 367.78$.

Usually, of course, the point estimate is less interesting than the error bars you can put around it, and how they change with the number of samples $s$. This seems a little non-trivial. I'll see if I can find something.

---

One can do the error-bar style analysis I mentioned for the mean estimator as proposed by Michael Lugo. For this:

Let $E_i := \{ \textrm{item i appears in the sample}\}.$ Let $$ f_1 := (1 - 1/n)^s \\ f_2 := (1- 2/n)^s $$

Note that \begin{align} P(E_i ) &= 1 - f_1 \\ P(E_i \cap E_j) &= 1 - 2f_1 + f_2 \end{align} the latter for $i \neq j$ (proof by inclusion-exclusion).

So, as we already have $$\mathbb{E}[D] = n (1 - f_1).$$

Further \begin{align} \mathbb{E}[D^2] &= n(1 - f_1) + (n^2 - n) (1 - 2f_1 + f_2)\\ &= n(f_1 - f_2) + n^2(f_2 - f_1^2) + n^2(1-f_1)^2\end{align}

which means that $$ \mathrm{var}[D]= n(f_1 - f_2) + n^2(f_2 - f_1^2) \le n f_1.$$ This means that $D$ concentrates well - with probability greater than $1 - \delta,$ $$ D \in n(1 - f_1) \pm \sqrt{ nf_1/\delta^2} $$

(The above is Tchebycheff's ineq. Note that the events $E_i$ are rather weakly correlated, since $f_2 \approx f_1^2 + O(sn^{-2} e^{-s/n})$ for large $s,n$, so quite possibly an exponential concentration can be derived using Dobrushin style methods. Too much work for now)

It remains to invert this, which is messy. I'll fill this in when I get the time. High level, I'm hoping for $O(\sqrt{D})$ error bars when $s \gtrsim n$.

---

Lastly, note that the generic support estimators give guarantees of estimating $n$ to within an error of $\varepsilon n$ with roughly $ \frac{n}{\log n} \log^2(1/\varepsilon)$ samples (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.01227). Note how amazing this is - you can get a really good estimate of the support size while (asymptotically) sampling much fewer items than the support size! (Of course, these will require knowing more than just $D$). I don't remember anymore, but I think there are lower bounds that are derived using uniform distributions that place a generic sample complexity constraint of $\Omega(n/\log n)$.

Comment: Using $s=1000, d=344$, I get $n \approx 368.4$ using the formula from my post. So, these approaches get very similar answers.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Indeed. The only difference is the $d/n-d$ correction term in the above, and this will usually be significantly smaller than $s,$ so it'll get basically the same answers. In fact the estimate you described seems much more amenable to error analysis because the equation is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Say I take $n$ samples and there are $N$ days in the year.  The probability of observing any given birthday in these $n$ samples is $1-(1-1/N)^n$ and so the expected number of distinct birthdays is $f(N, n) = N (1-(1-1/N)^n)$.

In the particular numerical example you gave, $f(368, 1000) \approx 343.79$ and $f(369, 1000) \approx 344.54$, so if I observe 344 distinct birthdays among 1000 draws I should figure there are about 369 distinct days in the year.

Unfortunately solving $k = N (1-(1-1/N)^n)$ for $N$ looks unpleasant, but it should be easy to do numerically.